# Status is 200 OK but the response is empty in Azure Functions (.NET 6) with Python Executable Application

Tags: python, c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0

Python File:

```py
num1 = 1.5
num2 = 6.3
sum = num1 + num2
print('The sum of {0} and {1} is {2}'.format(num1, num2, sum))
```

Azure Functions - .NET 6:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PyScriptTrigger
{
    public static class HttpTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("HttpTrigger")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string result = "";
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = @"C:\Users\HARIKA556\source\repos\Krishna\PyScriptTrigger\test.exe";
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    log.LogInformation("File Starting Executed");
                    result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    log.LogInformation("File executed");
                }
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Out of the Process block: " + result);

            return new OkObjectResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Not Sure where I missed the syntax, it is not giving the response both locally and in Azure Portal - Function App.

I'm not getting the result value in the output. It means the status comes 200 Ok but the output is not getting as expected.

Expected Result in the postman or Azure Function Portal App:
`The sum of 1.5 and 6.3 is 7.8'`

Comment: What is `test.exe`?

Comment: test.exe file is executable file of the python program test.py provided in the question.

Comment: How do you make that exe? Using pyinstaller?

Comment: yes, using the pyinstaller

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(result);` As far as I can see, this is the only thing you do with the program output.  If you want to return it as json, then you have to ... do that.

Comment: Your connection is good.  An empty response simply means the query you made to Azure database did not contain any results.

Comment: @HarikaReddy Can you try adding `flush=True` in the python print function and recompile the exe again?

Comment: I'm trying flush=true comment and will update in a while

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM and all, It is not printing the result out of the process block in the console - https://i.imgur.com/m1r5Miv.png

Comment: Locally, it is working as expected. Checking in the Azure portal Function App. I also updated the locally working code in the question.